# Prove that a sequence of linear maps is bounded iff its matrix representation is bounded.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of a finite dimensional vector space. We consider the following sequence of maps $(f^p)_p$. $M_B(f)$ is the matrix representation of $f$ in the basis $B$

The following statement holds:

The sequence of maps  $(f^p)_p$ is bounded if and only if the sequence of matrix $(M_B(f^p))_p$ is bounded.

I don't know how to proceed. I guess I need to find the suited norms.

Comment: A norm is always finite so both terms of your equivalence are always true.

Comment: Editing is done, the problem is valid now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "bounded", you mean, with respect to some norm. So you consider some norms $||.||_1$ on $L(E)$, space of endomorphisms  of $E$, and $||.||_2$ on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Given a basis $B$, the map $\Phi: f \mapsto M_B(f)$ gives an isomorphism from $L(E)$ to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Use $\Phi$ to define a norm on $L(E)$ by $||f||_{2'} := ||\Phi(f)||_2$.

Now, use the theorem of equivalence of norms, on a finite dimensional vector space over the real numbers.

Comment: I couldn't have come up with something better. Merci !